# How to UPDATE several specific columns using sqlite3 - python

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, tuples

I am trying to update several specific columns using sqlite3 and python 2.7. 
Im kind of new to sqlite3.

I have database that has 7 columns (id, date, columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE)

I need to update the five last columns (A,B,C,D,E) from the last row.
I have a tuple full of integers like this:

```
data = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I tryied this:

```
c.executemany("UPDATE database SET columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE =      (?,?,?,?,?) WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) from database))", data)
```

But I get an OperationalError.

Is there anyway I can do this with only one command?.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `UPDATE` syntax wrong, use:

```
c.execute(
    "UPDATE database SET columnA=?, columnB=?, columnC=?, columnD=?, columnE=? "
    "WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) from database))", 
    data)
```

Use `.execute()`; you are updating just one row, not several, and `data` contains just the values for one update.

See the [`UPDATE` documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).